# auth log filled with "Failed password for invalid user [user] from 127.0.0.1 port [port]"

Tags: security, debian

I'm pretty new to running a server still, and I've setup my own little sandbox on digital ocean.  I'm running a Debian build and I've started to get into securing my server.  Using iptables and fail2ban I've stopped all the thousands of requests from external IPs trying to crack into my server via SSH, but I still keep seeing:
`Failed password for invalid user [user] from 127.0.0.1 port [port]` with the `[user]` being my digital ocean account name and the `[port]` incrementing with each attempt so you'd see port 1234 then 1235, 1236, 1237...

Is this some internal service trying to perform something?  Or how can I get it to stop.  Or should I just not be concerned at all?

I tried looking for what it might be here on stack, google, and digital oceans pages with no luck.  Any info appreciated.  Thanks!